# Fill missing data in list by queering EF DBSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
List<ImageModel> Images;
```

Where all images in this list has Votes = 0 and ImageModel is:

```
public ImageModel {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 Votes { get; set; }
}
```

I need to:

1. Query context.Images and find the correspondent images by Id;
2. Get the votes of those images and fill into the List.

Image entity has the same properties:

```
public Image {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 Votes { get; set; }
  // More properties
}
```

**UPDATE**

I could do this:

```
context.Images.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Votes = x.Votes }).ToList()
```

Then loop through ImageModel list and fill with votes ...

But I do not want to query all images ... Only the ones which has the Id in ImageModel list ... So basically I need an instersection between images and context.Images by Id and fill the Votes into images list.

Comment: you have to do this by writing the code.. which that is nobody's job here .. what have you tried besides what you have posted..? where are you newing up Images..?

Comment: I just added an update with what I am trying to do ... Does it help?

Comment: you can do `Where` clauses in lambda statements as well btw..

Comment: Yes, sure ... But how to do the intersection between two lists by id?

Comment: look up how to use `FindAll().Where(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 context.Images.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>Images.Any(i=>i.Id==x.Id)).Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Votes = x.Votes }).ToList();
```

If you don't want to call the `AsEnumerable` method, then you have to select the ids from your `Image` List first as I show below:

```
 var ids = Images.Select(e => e.Id);
 context.Images.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Votes = x.Votes }).ToList();
```

Comment: I do not want to load all images in context into memory ... that is what asenumerable

Comment: The first query is not supported in EF if you don't call the AsEnumerable method first. I have updated my answer with a second option. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I was looking for a way of the query to automatically fill the data but this works to ...